# React - Converting object to string to display in DevExpress React Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, devexpress

I've just started using React along with the DevExpress React Grid.

However I'm facing an issue, when I'm trying to display the grid I get the error: 
`Objects are not valid as a React child`.

Now it appears that I need to convert any instances of objects in my data to a string, namely: `.toString()`.

However is there a built in way to do this in DevExpress's React Grid, or do I need to manually write some code to run through my data and update it.

FYI - the data I am working with (showing in my table) looks like:

```
chapters: [{
        id: "chapterId1",
        code: "chapterCode",
        policies: {
            startTime: "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z",
            endTime: "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z",
        },
}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where you got the error?

Comment: That error happens when you attempt to directly render an object. You'll need to render the object to a string first (via `.toString()` or `JSON.stringify(chapters)`) to display it in that way

Comment: Hey, I'm trying that JSON.stringify however not having much luck. So chapters is itself already an array. So when I pass it to the `rows` like: `rows={props.chapters}` I feel it expects me to `rows={[props.chapters.toString()]}`, but then I'm wrapping into another array? Also as a string can the DevExpress grid actually obtain the key, values?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely the `policies` key. It appears this library is trying to directly render that value but that value is an object.

One option would be to manually "flatten" this value into a single value or two separate values. For example:

```
{
  id: "chapterId1",
  code: "chapterCode",
  policies: "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z - 2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z"
}
```

The other approach if you want to distinct columns:

```
{
  id: "chapterId1",
  code: "chapterCode",
  policiesStart: "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z",
  policiesEnd: "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z"
}
```

I don't have the full context but assuming you want to format these dates you could create a helper (eg: `transformRows`) that accepts your current input and constructs this new input (and does additional work like date formatting):

```
const chapters = [
  {
    id: "chapterId1",
    code: "chapterCode",
    policies: {
      startTime: "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z",
      endTime: "2016-08-29T09:12:33.001Z"
    }
  }
];

const transformRows = rows =>
  rows.map(({ policies, ...rest }) => ({
    policiesStart: policies.startTime,
    policiesEnd: policies.endTime,
    ...rest
  }));

const App = () => (
  <Grid
    rows={transformRows(chapters)}
    columns={[
      { name: "id", title: "ID" },
      { name: "code", title: "Code" },
      { name: "policiesStart", title: "Policies" },
      { name: "policiesEnd", title: "Policies" }
    ]}
  >
    <Table />
    <TableHeaderRow />
  </Grid>
);
```